# my javascript delete button not working

Tags: javascript, html

[Here you can see what I mean please note the blue + sign that's what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGOjM.png)

to start off, this was a post I deleted because I was a mess, so I deleted it and made a new one make sure it looks a bit decent 
(as far as I could). I am trying to make a delete button but when I implement the delete button it prevents my script from running (most likely an error) if u take a look at the picture you can see a button that's green and a button that's blue. The blue button adds one input field when clicked on. that's the 
"getAddBtn", as u can see in the picture. However, I now made a function called "getRemoveBtn" and this should do the same like the blue button but reverse. It should delete one input field... in case you had clicked on the blue button too often. I tried putting my "getRemoveBtn" in the piece of code:

"$(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), 
 getWordPartInput(i),getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

return eBlock;
}"

but when I do it messes up every functionality and it displays an empty page with just my css/bootstrap. either I am NOT implementing the code in the right way in the piece of code that should or my code straight up sucks. Both possibilities could because I am quite new to javascript. I would like to have the button work the exact same way as the blue button but then remove one input field instead of adding one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id = 0;
var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
   'class': 'btn btn-success',
   'id': 'addOpdracht'
}).on('click', function(){
    $('.panel-body').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    id++;
}).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');

$('.jumbotron').append(addOpdracht);
 })


 function getAddBtn(target, i){
 var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
 return addBtn;
  }


 function getRemoveBtn(target, i){
 var removeBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).empty(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
return removeBtn;
 }



 function getExerciseBlock(i){
   var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
   'id': i,
   'class': 'col-md-12'
 });

 $(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), 
 getWordPartInput(i),getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

  return eBlock;
}


  function getAudioBtn(id, cValue){
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
 }


 function getWordInput(id, cValue){
   cValue = cValue || '';
 var wInput = $('<input/>', {
                'class': 'form-group form-control',
                'type': 'text',
                'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
                'placeholder': 'Exercise',
                'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'
            })
  return wInput;
}


function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
   cValue = cValue || '';
   var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
                  'class': 'form-group form-control',
                  'type': 'text',
                  'value': cValue,
                  'placeholder': 'Syllables',
                  'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput'
              });
 return wpInput;
}
```

Comment: what error u are getting on page load ?

Comment: "it messes up every functionality and it displays an empty page with just my css/bootstrap."   Have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: Yeah right... horrible code, sorry for not being as experienced like you. i'm sorry for practicing man! appreciate the "help". @AshishRatan Ratan it doesn't exactly give an error on page load. It just shows me css/bootstrap layout, but I lose all the buttons etc.

Comment: i didnt mean that your code is horrible, im saying that jquery is, especially for a beginner to use. it also seems overkill for just a button

Comment: I have to use it for my college project. I didn't choose to do so, but they force me. so I have nothing to go against.